# Solving a multivariate non-linear system of equations using Newton's method

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, newton-raphson

I'm doing a report on the mathematics of GPS, and I have the following equations to solve for $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t_b$:

[image: System of equations]

I'm using Newton's method, with the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives being as follows (by the power rule):

[image: Jacobian matrix]

I'm using an initial guess of:

[image: Initial guess]

I've substituted in the initial guess to give what should be the first iteration using Newton's method:

[image]

Which simplifies to give:

[image: First iteration]

However, this evaluates to:

[image]

The correct first iteration however, as calculated by Maxima, is:

[image]

Where have I gone wrong in this? I've self-taught myself most of this mathematics, and the fact that my iteration is so different from the correct one means I've probably done something completely wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using Octave (and your numbers above), I get the first iteration as $\approx (-18907, 21558, -23811, 0.567)^T$. The condition number of $J$ is fairly large ($\approx 6 \times 10^7$). As an aside, you should really start with numbers close to a solution, as the behaviour of Newton's method away from a zero can be quite wild.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.

I repeated the calculations but set all numbers as rational. The results I obtained are $$x=-\frac{5092356599265080239}{142135566553125000}\approx-35.82746193$$ $$y=-\frac{51362394942211922323}{142135566553125000}\approx-361.3620165$$ $$z=-\frac{315241754157890072131}{7896420364062500}\approx-39922.10896$$ $$t=\frac{28067559633057906988253}{51100601628870148500000}\approx0.5492608450$$ which are identical to those Maxima gave.

Setting all numbers as decimals, I ended with the same results.

As  copper.hat commented, the system is very badly conditioned ($J\approx 6\times 10^7$) and I wonder what could happen working with low precision. Could you precise this point ?

Just for your curiosity, the problem has two solutions $$\{x\to -41.7663,y\to -16.7878,z\to 6370.2,t\to -0.00319939\}\}$$ $$\{x\to -39.7413,y\to
   -134.276,z\to -9413.92,t\to 0.185171\}$$

**Edit**

If I may suggest, I should not use Newton for this kind of problem. Expand $f_1-f_2$, $f_1-f_3$, $f_1-f_3$; all squares disappear and you have $$f_1-f_2=-\frac{1312248584 }{5}t+6320 x-9580 y-3060 z+\frac{1172267578731}{62500}=0$$ $$f_1-f_3=-\frac{5536610464 }{5}t+4020 x+14180 y-13320 z+\frac{1276786201414}{15625}=0$$ $$f_1-f_4=-\frac{1509984672 }{5}t+7140 x-13860 y-3500 z+\frac{334297508818}{15625}=0$$ from which you can eliminate $y,z,t$ as linear functions of $x$; report these expressions in $f_1$ and you get a quadratic equation in $x$ $$x^2+\frac{1172085587221693444650100593
   }{14380080939595292010312500}x+\frac{3729488115129024118430005986528113}{224688764
   6811764376611328125000}=0 $$ Solve it and back to $y,z,t$.

This is a general method for this kind of equations.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "set all numbers as rational"? Have I done everything right but just calculated it wrong?

Comment: Also, as far as the other method goes, my report is only focusing on Newton's method. Thanks for letting me know about that though. :)

Comment: First, could you tell me what is your machine precision ? If you don't know, compute the largest value of $n$ such that $1+2^{-n}>1$. Second, tell the person who will get your report that there are explicit solutions to the problem. Did you calculate wrong ? difficult to answer ! I transformed the decimal numbers to rational numbers in order to use illimited precision but, for my environment, it was not required. Cheers.